# Autocomplete from jQuery returns Label values, I would like to return the values

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, autocomplete

I am having trouble getting the auto-complete wrapper getting filled with the values, not the labels

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#id_name').autocomplete({            
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'proiecte:autocomplete' %}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        term: request.term
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data.name, function(value, key) {    
                                             
                            return {                                
                                value: data.name[key],
                                label: data.id[key],
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },           
        })
    });
```

I've added an image for example, the auto-complete should show text values not numbers:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type in the textbox it shows the id because you
assigned it in your label.

Try interchanging your value and label assignment with the one below.

```
success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.name, function(value, key) {    
                                         
                        return {                                
                            value: data.id[key],
                            label: data.name[key],
                        }
                    }));
                }
```

Comment: yeah, of course that was the problem ,thank you, but now when I make the selection in the input it returns the label value.